# how to create an entry that begins with a dollar sign in python tkinter

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, pycharm

how can i create an entry that begins with a dollar sign so i don't have to enter the sign every time into the entry in python tkinter here is the code

```
price = Entry(Forms, textvariable=PRICE, width=30)
price.grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: @BryanOakley it does have an entry widget but i want to add a dollar sign in the entry widget everytime i launch the software

Comment: you can set text `$` in `PRICE` and then it will display it in `Entry` but user may delete it - so I would rather use `Label` to display it on the left of `Entry`

Comment: @furas thank you Soo much for the creative answer!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set text in `PRICE` at start

```
PRICE = tk.StringVar(value='$')
```

or

```
PRICE.set('$')
```

and then `Entry(..., textvariable=PRICE)` will display it at start. But user can delete it and would need more work to block it.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
        
root = tk.Tk()

PRICE = tk.StringVar(value='$')
#PRICE.set('$')

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=PRICE)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

I would rather put `$` as Label on the left of `Entry` and then user can write only number.

```
import tkinter as tk
        
root = tk.Tk()

PRICE = tk.StringVar()

label = tk.Label(root, text='$')
label.grid(row=0, column=0)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=PRICE)
entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```